# How to learn assigned adress to pointer? (Address assigned from a variable) is it possible?

Tags: c

```
int number;
int *ptr;
    
ptr = &number;

printf("ptr: %d", *ptr);
printf("number: %p", &number);
```

After assigning the address of the variable to the pointer, I want the variable to output its address and the pointer to output the address of the variable.

EDIT:

```
int number;
int *ptr;
    
ptr = &number;

printf("ptr: %p", *ptr);
printf("number: %p", &number);
```

I tried this code and its gave me same adresses.

Comment: Do you want `printf("ptr: %p", ptr);`?

Comment: If you want the variable to output its address and the pointer to output the address of the variable, do you want to see the same thing printed twice?

Comment: yes i want to see same thing printed twice with different ways :( just curiosity @AnthonyDiGiovanna

Comment: I tried but it give to me different adresses @stark

Comment: Please show the code that gives you different addresses.

Comment: I added the post. Do you think I did it right? @thebusybee

Comment: When you do `*ptr`, you are asking for the _value_ stored at the address. `ptr` is already the address, no operators needed. `&number` will return the address of `number`, as you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do what you're looking for. using %p in printf will print the address that the pointer is pointing to.

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    int *ptr;
        
    ptr = &number;
    
    printf("ptr: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("number: %p", &number);
}
```